# Building a simple Hello World gives error MSB8040

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

I have installed **Visual Studio** to do some tests in C. The "Hello World" sample worked OK.

Then I installed **WDK** foreseeing to do some tests in future. However, when I now try to compile the same "Hello World" in C++ I get this error:

```
Error   MSB8040:
Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project. Install them from the Visual Studio installer (Individual components tab) for any toolsets and architectures being used. Learn more: https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c
  Test1
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  436
```

This is coming from the WDK installation, but honestly I don't understand very well why I'm getting it, since I didn't "enable" any Driver development or similar. I just want to compile my simple Hello World.

I don't want to install anything that is not really necessary. I have tried to disable WDK from the Extensions menu and some others but nothing helped.

How can I disable this error so I can build the program normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest solution is to disable the `Spectre Mitigation` option.

Go to:

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Spectre Mitigation
```

And set it to:

```
Disabled
```